# a method that recieves String input and divides it into 1,2 and 3 different sections

Tags: java

i need a more basic method! that will just split words into 1,2,3 consecutive compartments, my output for "water" should be in terms of array string! e.g INPUT of water should produce OUTPUT like {"w","a","t","e","r","wa","at","te","er","wat","ate","ter"}

```
public void split(String word) {

    int x=(word.length())/2;
    int z=word.length();
    String[] partition= new String[5];

   for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
       String new1=Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
       String new2 = Character.toString(word.charAt(i))+Character.toString(word.charAt(i+1));
       String new3 = Character.toString(word.charAt(i))+Character.toString(word.charAt(i+1))+Character.toString(word.charAt(i+2));
       String new4 = removeDuplicate(Character.toString(word.charAt(z-2))+ Character.toString(word.charAt(z-1)));
       String new5 = removeDuplicate(Character.toString(word.charAt(z-3))+ Character.toString(word.charAt(z-2))+ Character.toString(word.charAt(z-1)));
       char result = word.charAt(2);
       String[] partitions = {new1,new5,new3,new4,new2};

       //partition=partitions;
       //Arrays.toString((removeDuplicates(partitions)))
       System.out.println(partitions);
   }
   //return partition;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing it for yourself?  This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Show us an attempt that you couldn't get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do that. I hope if you are not a beginner you know about `ArrayList`.

```
String word = "water";
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    int limit = word.length() - i + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
        list.add(word.substring(j, j+i));
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output :

```
[w, a, t, e, r, wa, at, te, er, wat, ate, ter]
```

Try to understand it. and tell me if having any doubt.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on tick when you found any answer useful or best when there are more then 1 useful answers. This way the answerer will gain 15 reputations and you will gain 2. (Just to let you know if you are unaware) @KutloSekwamote

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] foo(String word){
    String[] consec = new String[3*word.length() - 3];
    String substr;
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= word.length() - i; j++){
            substr = word.substring(j, j+i);
            consec[k] = substr;
            k++;
        }

    }
    return consec;
}
```